# How to lock/unlock cross thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

For some code snippets, I want to execute one by one, something like:

```
self.coreDataLock = [[NSRecursiveLock alloc] init];

// Snippet One
[self.coreDataLock lock];
[childContext performBlock:^{
    // Do something
    [self.coreDataLock unlock];
}];

// Snippet Two
[self.coreDataLock lock];
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do something
    [self.coreDataLock unlock];
});
```

But I can't lock/unlock NSRecursiveLock cross thread, how to figure it out?

Comment: It looks like you are using Core Data. Are you doing all of your work within `[context performBlock: ...]` blocks? If so, you do not need to lock, as Core Data will execute the blocks one at a time, in order of submission. If not, how about using a serial queue instead of a lock?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Core Data, I'm doing all work within performBlock, but I have many performBlock cross different function. could you share more information about the queue you are talking about?